# MYSQL: Unix_Timestamp How to deduct 2 weeks

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

I have had a look all over, but it doesn't seem as though my required coding is addressed anywhere. 
Please note that the "interval" variable does NOT work for me. Please use the current code, which works well to show all dates in CURRENT week.

The code below splits all dates in the current week out, but how do I adjust this to split out the prior week? (Sun to Sat)

```
    IF(FROM_UNIXTIME(renprop_commercial_new.tstamp, "%U") =  FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()),"%U"),1,0)
```

I have tried adding a minus 7 (for days) behind the "%U", but it causes the script to be positive for every date.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deduct `1209600` (twice the number of seconds in a week) from `NOW()`.

```
IF(FROM_UNIXTIME(renprop_commercial_new.tstamp, "%U") =  FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()-1209600),"%U"),1,0)
```

Alternatively, you can use `DATE_SUB()`:

```
IF(FROM_UNIXTIME(renprop_commercial_new.tstamp, "%U") =  FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK)),"%U"),1,0)
```

Comment: Thanks, the final code is as follows:
        IF(FROM_UNIXTIME(renprop_commercial_new.tstamp, "%U") =  FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()),"%U"-604800),1,0)
Tested and works like a charm! You definitely helped me

Comment: @hermanvn: Note that `604800` is for only one week, I originally misread your question and edited the correct value for 2 weeks in later.

Answer (score 0):

Although I prefer using interval this should do the trick :

```
IF(FROM_UNIXTIME(1340341200, "%U") =  FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())-(7*24*60*60),"%U"),1,0);
```

Comment: Thanks, this query has been closed! Had to wait a while until it would accept my tick.